# CalendarApp not working in google sheet addon

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm using `google apps script` to make a addon for spreadsheets where spreadsheet datas will be used to create events in google calendar. Everything is working except if I run the code from my testing addon, events are not adding in calendar for some reason. But if I run the code from my script then it works fine. Here are my codes,

```
function createEvent(date, start_time, end_time, event_title)
{
  var dateCol = 0;
  var startCol = 0;
  var endCol = 0;
  var titleCol=0;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = dataSheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var lc = dataSheet.getLastColumn();

  var rng = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc).getValues();

  // This will match the column corresponsing to our selected value in dropdown from html sidebar.
  for (var i=0; i < rng[0].length; i++)
  {
    if (date == rng[0][i]) {
      dateCol = i;
    }
    if (start_time == rng[0][i]) {
      startCol = i;
    }
    if (end_time == rng[0][i]) {
      endCol = i;
    }
    if (event_title == rng[0][i]) {
      titleCol = i;
    }
  }

  // This part handles the creating of an event in calendar
  var getUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  var getCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(getUser);

  var data_rng = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, lc).getValues();

  for (var j=0; j < data_rng.length; j++)
  {
    var getDate = new Date(data_rng[j][dateCol]);
    var getDate2 = new Date(data_rng[j][dateCol]);

    var getStart =new Date(data_rng[j][startCol]);
    var getEnd = new Date(data_rng[j][endCol]);

    getDate.setHours(getStart.getHours());
    getDate.setMinutes(getStart.getMinutes());

    getDate2.setHours(getEnd.getHours());
    getDate2.setMinutes(getEnd.getMinutes());

    var title = data_rng[j][titleCol];
    getCal.createEvent(title, getDate, getDate2);
  }
}
```

Do I need to do something else to get it work on addon? How can I make the CalendarApp work on addon?

Comment: You need to debug your code from the Add-on.  You can write out data to a log spreadsheet, or send yourself an email if there is an error.  You can use the "Publish", "Test as Add-on" option and trigger the function from a menu item for testing.   You can add a `Logger.log('ss: ' + ss);` statement and see if the code is getting the active spreadsheet.   I don't know if you can use "getActiveSpreadsheet()" with an Add-on.  Try getting the spreadsheet by ID.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, I'm already sure that it's getting the active spreadsheet, it's the CalendarApp that's not working from the addon, any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know that myself and others have not had much success with the `getEffectiveUser()` method.  That's what I immediately am suspicious of.